# Sort algorithm in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What kind of algorithm is used in Kotlin language?

For example in my Android app:

```
myArrayList.sortByDescending { it.enums.ordinal }
```

If it matters i am using Kotlin version 1.3.41, and I found out that, for example Java uses TimSort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin uses the same sorting algorithm as Java.

This can be seen in the source code at: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/7c77565bb8b42f45d41c7948b2d2f7f5931f7c34/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollectionsJVM.kt#L30